# How to set a value of type long to Weka Instance?

Tags: java, weka

How can i add or set a long value to Weka Instance? So far i only found instance.setValue() but as the attached URL stated that setValue can only takes int or double: http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/Instance.html

Can anyone advise me please?

Thank you
KP

Answer (score 0):

Question closed, there is no way to do now. As internally, Weka uses doubles for representing the data, so i can only use the method that takes a double.